# Are the relationships in this ER Digram correct?

Tags: database-design, erd

I'm creating an ER Diagram to capture the following:

- A USER may belong to one or more GROUPs
- A GROUP must have one or more USERs
- A GROUP may have active one or more EXERCISE TYPE
- A USER may participate in one or more EXERCISE TYPE
- A USER achieves number of REPS on a DATE for an EXERCISE TYPE

[image: FITNESS ERD]

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: There are many ER & pseudo-ER methods for design & diagrams. What is the reference (eg textbook name & edition & chapter) that you are supposed to use? PS Achieves is date-reps pairs somehow related, although you don't say how. If I give you such a date-rep pair & the rest of the data here, is that useful? (Answer: No.)

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--you will likely find mistakes that make your question unnecessary & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went wrong & right. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but I think you're missing two things.

1. An EXERCISE table should be used to hold comprehensive data for exercises. It should have the columns EXERCISE TYPE, REPS, and DATE with EXERCISE TYPE being a foreign key to the EXERCISE TYPE table.
2. The relationship between USER and GROUP is many-to-many. This should be eliminated with an associative (intermediate) table you could call MEMBERSHIP to store each individual group membership. The relationship should then be
   `USER 1..n MEMBERSHIP n..1 GROUP`.

These changes will [normalize](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the structure. I strongly recommend reading about the stages of normalization. Knowing how to normalize a database and what stage to stop at is invaluable.

Comment: @Rednaxela & Adam Those changes have nothing to do with normalization. Find out what normalization is. PS "The relationship between USER and GROUP" *is* the diamond "belongs to" & *is represented by* "an associative (intermediate) table" which would (per the diamond) be called "belongs to" aka your MEMBERSHIP.

Comment: @Rednaxela & Adam Chen true ER diagrams use a diamond for a relationship/association (relational table) & a line as participation (relational FK). Here, given the text, the line marks are Chen cardinalities, normally annotated by text. The asker should be giving a legend for their diagram. Crows feet are from pseudo-ER diagrams of pseudo-ER pre-ER methods where "relationship" means FK. The Wikipedia ER article is more or less OK re this.